How to keep shrinking/expanding edges static in a NetworkX rewiring process
I'm working with NetworkX to build a network that undergoes a rewiring process. The rewiring is generated by a loop whose iterations may produce a change in the weight of the edges. Those edges whose weights became heavier should shrink and make its component nodes approach to each other. Those edges whose weights became lighter should see their component nodes separate farther from each other. So, in other words, edges that became heavier after a loop round should appear shorter, with their nodes located closer to one another. And the other way round if weights become lighter (edges should become longer, with their nodes appearing more distant).
To assess the changes of the network (and to see how it rewires), I created a gif with all the images that the loop produces after all the iterations. However, it's not working. The edges never keep their initial position, so its difficult to assess evolution in the network, and plus, the gif shows a tendency to align all edges in a straight line (see bellow).
I have tried the following idea. I have created a function called adjust_node_positions based on:

the nodes positions,
what I understand to be the direction of the edges (that, as I say, should remain unchanged),
a factor (that increases or decreases the size of the edge):

def adjust_node_positions(G: nx.Graph, node1: str, node2: str, factor: float):
    
    positions = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos')
    
    # Compute the direction vector of the edge
    edge_vector = positions[node1] - positions[node2]
    
    new_distance = np.linalg.norm(edge_vector) * factor
    displacement = (new_distance - np.linalg.norm(edge_vector)) / 2  # Divide by 2 to split displacement evenly between the two nodes
       
    # Normalize the edge vector to get the direction
    direction = edge_vector / np.linalg.norm(edge_vector)
    
    # Update node positions
    positions[node1] += direction * displacement
    positions[node2] -= direction * displacement
    nx.set_node_attributes(G, positions, 'pos')


As I say, starting with a random layout for my network (nx.spring_layout), I can't preserve the original position/orientation of the edges. The gif shows them finally tending to align to a straight line, as if they all changed their orientation converging along to a straight line:

And this shows that I'm doing something -or several things- wrong.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

I think the code is correct. This behaviour is the expected outcome of the rule set if factor is greater than 1 (on average). 1. Moving a node pair (u, v), changes the distances to all neighbours (u, X), and (v, Y). 2. Long edges result in larger displacements. 3. On average, the distance |uX| and |vY| increase in the direction uv. 4. Eventually, all nodes will eventually be moved along the direction of the longest edge.
